# Azure Devops for terraform deployment - variables block yml file - problem

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am preparing terraform deployment using Azure devops pipelines. I am storing all my variables in `yml` file, all worked fine, but now I am trying to use `IF` statement in my `yml` variables file. I am using structure like below presented, and it does not work.

```
variables:
  # Environment/Git Branch condition
  environment: $(Build.SourceBranchName)

  # Environment check - DEV or PROD
  ${{ if eq(variables['environment'], 'DEV') }}:
    # Application Network parameters - DEV
    address_space_01: '10.0.0.0/16'
    address_space_02: '10.1.0.0/16'
    address_space_03: '10.2.0.0/16'

  ${{ elseif eq(variables['environment'], 'prod') }}:
    # Application Network parameters - PROD
    address_space_01: '10.4.0.0/16'
    address_space_02: '10.5.0.0/16'
    address_space_03: '10.6.0.0/16'
```

I does not work, when azure devops pipeline trying to perform terraform deployment on Azure cloud,  it throws an error `each.value is ""`, so it means that all values of properties `address_space_0x:` are not passed properly to the terraform modules.

Comment: try to use the `$(Build.SourceBranchName)` in the condition

Comment: I tried this, but didnt work. Could you please paste condition format you use. Maybe I used wrongly formatted „if” condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend to give values to Terraform variables in the pipeline like this way.

You should give values to terraform variables either at the resource level or at module level if you use terraform modules.

But please don’t give values in pipeline like this, it’s not a best approach.

If you have to create 10 different virtual networks, then how will you handle that ? If you keep following this approach .

could you please try below approach:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}:
   address_space_01: '10.0.0.0/16'
   address_space_02: '10.1.0.0/16'
   address_space_03: '10.2.0.0/16'

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'prod') }}:
    address_space_01: '10.4.0.0/16'
    address_space_02: '10.5.0.0/16'
    address_space_03: '10.6.0.0/16'
```

Comment: Hi, When I am using three different variables in following format `address_space_01: '10.4.0.0/16' address_space_02: '10.4.0.0/16' address_space_03: '10.4.0.0/16'`, values are in three lines. Mentioned approach works as expected, I have loops in my terraform module. It only does not work when I using `IF` statement in `yml` variable file.

Comment: what is the name of your branches ? Is there any error you see ?

Comment: My branches arę prod and dev, i need to use variables from „if”block when using dev branch, and use „elseif” block when using prod branch.

Comment: As i understand , you got the error :  each.value is "", so that means the value was not passed correctly from the pipeline. So, did it happen for dev branch ? Because i see you have used 'DEV' in the if block instead of 'dev'.

Comment: Exactly, there is a problem with if condition statement in yml variable file, i tried DEV and dev.

Comment: Thanks Sunny Nazar, works perfectly fine, thanks a lot!!! Merry Christmas!! :)

Comment: Great. Wish you too a "Merry Christmas" !

Answer (score 0):

Below correct structure of YML variables file:

```
variables:
  # Environment/Git Branch condition
  environment: $(Build.SourceBranchName)

  # Environment check - DEV or PROD
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}:
    # Application Network parameters - DEV
    address_space_01: '10.0.0.0/16'
    address_space_02: '10.1.0.0/16'
    address_space_03: '10.2.0.0/16'

  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'prod') }}:
    # Application Network parameters - PROD
    address_space_01: '10.4.0.0/16'
    address_space_02: '10.5.0.0/16'
    address_space_03: '10.6.0.0/16'
```